# Mongo script to update an object if its a certain value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to update a document in Mongo if it has a certain value within a field.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("myObject"),
    "source" : "BW",
    "sourceTableName" : "myTable",
    "tableName" : "tier",
    "type" : "main",
    "fieldMappings" : [ 
        {
            "sourceField" : "tier_id", <~~~~ If this is "tier_id", I want to change it to "trmls_id"
            "reportingField" : "bw_id",
            "type" : "integer",
            "defaultMap" : {
                "shouldErrorOnConvert" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried something like

```
db.getCollection('entityMap').update({"sourceTableName":"myTable"}, {"fieldMappings.0.sourceField":"trmls_id":{$exists : true}}, { $set: { "fieldMappings.0.sourceField": "tier_id" } })
```

and I think it is failing on the `$exists` parameter I am setting.

Is there a more cleaner/dynamic way to do this?

The whole query I am trying to formulate is

1. In the table `myTable`
2. I want to check **if** there is a sourceField that has the value `tier_id`
3. If there is `tier_id`, then change it to `trmls_id`
4. Otherwise do nothing

If there is a similar StackOverflow question that answers this, I am happy to explore it! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, no, `{key:thing1:thing2}` is not valid syntax

Comment: Your query is malformed. It needs to contain valid Objects.

Comment: `db.getCollection('entityMap').update({ 'sourceTableName': 'myTable', 'fieldMappings.sourceField': 'tier_id' '}, ...)`  would be the selector part at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax mistake and you can use positional operator `$` in update part because you have already selector field in query part,

```
db.getCollection('entityMap').update(
  { 
      "sourceTableName": "myTable",
      "fieldMappings.sourceField": "tier_id" // if this field found then it will go to update part
  }, 
  {
      $set: {
          "fieldMappings.$.sourceField": "trmls_id"
      }
  }
)
```

Comment: That is perfect dude! I guess I didn't know how to compartmentalize the selectors. Thanks man.